# Variable value calculated at runtime/at request time

Tags: python, robotframework

I am trying to find a way the value of a variable to be evaluated every time when it is used. That is opposite of the normal operation of the Robot Framework - variables are set when defined.

Consider this example - a py variables file:

```
import random


MY_VAR = random.randint(1,100)
```

The variable will be set to an int, and then keep its value on every usage. Thus when used in this call:

```
Log To Console    Value ${MY VAR}, again ${MY VAR}
```

, will print the same number.

What I've considered:

- A keyword/method that calculates & returns the value, and on the next line it's used. Not really feasible, in my use case those vars are used hundreds of times, and this adds boilerplate plus implied knowledge *("you must use the method before every usage!")*.
- Listener interface, `_start_suite`, or case or keyword - that's the closest to a "constructor" in the framework; negatives - executed once at the corresponding level, adds runtime overhead.

---

Basically, I need a python's `@property` decorator on a (semi-) normal Robot Framework variable, or passing a method call as an argument :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [inline python evaluation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#id117) to execute a function in a variable. In the following example, different random numbers will be logged three times:

```
*** Test cases ***
Example
    log  ${{random.randint(1, 100)}}
    log  ${{random.randint(1, 100)}}
    log  ${{random.randint(1, 100)}}
```

---

If the call is for a method created by the user (not in the installed packages), then it is `module_name.method_name()`. For example if there's a method `my_method(param1)` in a module `my_module.py`, this is how to call it:

```
Log  ${{my_modlue.my_method('arg')}}
```

---

If the target is a RF keyword, it's a bit more cumbersome - one needs to use the `run_keyword()` method in the `BuiltIn` class. Example - calling the keyword `My Keyword`:

```
Log  ${{robot.libraries.BuiltIn.BuiltIn().run_keyword('argument1')}}
```

Comment: Yes, that'll do; in my usage it is not a standard lib's method or imported package, but custom methods. Extended the answer how to go with those, plus RF keywords (for which I couldn't get a shorter version than this). Thanks for the hint!